# max number of supported MAC addresses in Catalyst series switch

Tags: cisco-catalyst

Is there a command to view maximum number of MAC address entries in CAM table in Catalyst series switches? I have usually found this information from release notes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but this might be platform dependent.

For example, on Cisco 4900M:

```
4900M#show mac address-table count 
MAC Entries for all vlans:
Dynamic Unicast Address Count:                  8507
Static Unicast Address (User-defined) Count:    130
Static Unicast Address (System-defined) Count:  18
Total Unicast MAC Addresses In Use:             8655
Total Unicast MAC Addresses Available:          55000
Multicast MAC Address Count:                    28
Total Multicast MAC Addresses Available:        32768
```

Cisco 3560G:

```
3560#show mac address-table count 
Mac Entries for Vlan 738:
---------------------------
Dynamic Address Count  : 1
Static  Address Count  : 0
Total Mac Addresses    : 1
[...]
Total Mac Address Space Available: 5894
```